# SP16- Multiple WebParts in SPFx Project For Classic pages(On-premise FP2)

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts

Can i add multiple webparts in my SPFX project for sharepoint server 2016 - classic pages. All samples are for modern pages like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5UocF8mcQ).

New webpart where i trying to add in my existing project is with another name, but error is:

> Cannot create two Web part (on-prem) with the same name

**I have following error:**
[image]

Where i install latest version on  **@microsoft/generator-sharepoint** i solving above problem.

**Modern Page:**

[image]

But doesn't work for classic pages.

Comment: Have you noticed that the error message is "Cannot create two Web part (on-prem) with the same name."?

Comment: Yes, new webpart where i trying to add in existing project is with another name.

Comment: what version of yeoman are you using ? can you update it to the latest version and check ?

Comment: yeoman version is - yo@2.0.0

Comment: Sorry, i meant install the latest version of the sharepoint generator as `npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g` and then check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue has been resolved in the `SPFx v1.3.4`.

Update the your sharepoint generator to this version to resolve the issue.

To update the generator, use the below command and then run the generator again to create multiple webparts in the same solution:

```
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g
```

Comment: The new web part is not displayed on the classic page

Comment: I think it will be there in the webpart gallery, can you add it from there ?